# Using walberla framework

Tags: frameworks, simulation, large-scale

I have a code for Latice model written in C. I want to link my code with waLBerla library which is written by C++. Unfortunately, there is no tuto on internet explaining or giving examples how to use walberla for large-scale simulations. Could someone provide or explain to me some examples on how to include walberla library in the main code?

Thanks________________

Comment: Moderators at strike https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an - so I also will not do **any** (further) content/curation-related action here